# Custom Component in Android View

Tags: android, custom-component

I have to create a custom component like this:

[image: Custom Component]

How to write its custom component?

Comment: You can use just use a `EditText` for you purpose, all you need is to set a varies of attributions.

Comment: you can use EditText in your layout XML as follows:

<EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/round_profile_icon"/>
Add drawable padding as per your layout design guidline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting icon on left side of edittext, you can use this:

```
android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/icon_username"
```

where "icon_username" is an image

Set hint like this:

```
android:hint="username"
```

To draw border around edittext you should use separate drawable file(xml file)

Sample code for drawable file:

`edittext_lines.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item  android:top="30dp">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Final code may look like:

```
<EditText 
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:hint="Username"
       android:background="@drawable/edittext_lines"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/round_profile_icon"/>
```